# if variable is true, DON'T SHOW alert? Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, alert

So basically, what I'm trying to find out, is if there is any way to set a variable to false, and NOT SHOW an alert message if said variable is changed to true.

example:

```
function pausePop() {
    $("#signatures").hover(function() {
        var shown = false;
        alert('If you hover over the signatures or the cleared sides, it will pause the scroll');
        var shown = true;

        if (shown = true) {

        }
    });
}
```

Is there any way to do this? If so, is there a SIMPLE way to do this? I am a mere beginner and would like to do some cool things right off the bat.

Comment: How would the variable get changed to true?  In other words, which state (think in terms of the world, not in terms of this particular variable) would cause the alert box not to be shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the context, but if you'd like to trigger the alert only once and then mark it as shown, try:

```
var shown = false;

function pausePop() {
    if (!shown) {
        alert('If you hover over the signatures or the cleared sides, it will pause the scroll');
        shown = true;
    }
}

$("#signatures").hover(pausePop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsFiddle that shows you some vary basic concepts related to your question:

- [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jahroy/VN7sy/)

Feel free to modify it however you like.

Here's a preview of the code:

```
var showAlert = true;

$('#hoverDiv').hover(function () {
    if (showAlert) {
        alert("Make sure you read this... You will only see it once.");
    }
    showAlert = false;
});
```

Comment: Well this helps a little, but not quite what I'm looking for. Let me see if I can clarify. If you hover over a div, a pop up should appear, you click okay, and it disappears, and doesn't reappear unless you reload the page.

Comment: I wasn't trying to solve your problem for you.  I was trying to show **you** how to solve your problem.  You should be able to do what you want pretty easily if you understand what's happening in the fiddle.  I find it strange that you state your problem so clearly in the above comment, but not in your original question.

Comment: @Articulous - I modified the fiddle to do exactly what you want.  Obviously you're more interested in copy/pasting code than learning...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are starting Javascript as your first programming language or you are just playing with some code.

The problem is not about Javascript, its about conditional if/else statements and flow of execution.

you dont need if/else also, if alert is shown execution pauses on that line. 
after client clicks the ok button,
next statement will be evaluated.